# Utilidad de “”.join()

Tags: python, python-3.x, join

Me gustaría saber la utilidad y funcionalidad de este método (en realidad no sé si es un método) `".".join`. Lo he observado en varios ejemplos y foros pero su concepto aun no me acaba de quedar claro. Si me pudieseis poner algún ejemplo de su utilidad lo mas sencillo posible os lo agradecería.

En concreto estoy intentado entender su funcionalidad con el siguiente ejemplo:

```
 #Complementariedad de cadenas de ADN
#solicitar al usuario la cadena:
 sequence = str(input('Enter DNA sequence:'))

# creacion del diccionario con sensibilidad de mayusculas y minisculas.

dic = {"A":"T" or "t", 
      "T":"A",
      "C":"G", 
      "G":"C", "a": "T", "t": "A", "c": "G", "g": "C" }
#salida de datos. Cadena complementaria.
print(''.join([dic[bases] for bases in sequence]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) es un método de instancia de la clase `str` que recibe como argumento de entrada un iterable que contiene cadenas y retorna una cadena uniendo los elementos del iterable con la cadena propietaria del método:

```
>>> iterable = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
>>> cadena_de_unión = " - "
>>> resultado = cadena_de_unión.join(iterable)
>>> resultado
'1 - 2 - 3 - 4'
```

Si la cadena de unión es un string vacío se limitará a concatenar los elementos del iterable en una única cadena.

En tu caso, para una entrada `AGGTCCGAA` el código (lista por compresión):

```
[dic[bases] for bases in sequence]
```

retorna una lista de strings:

```
['T', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'G', 'G', 'C', 'T', 'T']
```

Cuando sobre esa lista se aplica `"".join()` se limita a unir (concatenar) cada elemento de la lista (ya que la cadena de unión es una cadena vacía), es decir:

```
TCCAGGCTT
```

Comment: ok, muchas gracias